# Split strings with alternative separators

Tags: python, string

I would like to have alternative separator when calling `string.split()`

```
>>> import string
>>> string.split('a n', ' ')
['a', 'n']
```

which is correct.

```
>>> string.split('a n"c', ' "')
['a n"c']
>>> string.split('a n"c', '[ |"]')
['a n"c']
```

The ideal split should be `['a', 'n', 'c']`.

```
>>> string.split('a n" "c', '[ |"]')
['a n" "c']
>>> string.split('a n" "c', ' "')
['a n"', 'c']
```

The ideal split should be `['a', 'n', 'c']`.

So I wonder how can I do that?

Comment: `string.split()` is deprecated; you can call the method directly on strings.

Comment: why is it deprecated? Isn't that similar to C++? (which is good imho)

Comment: Because `'a b c'.split()` works too; those are methods on the `str` object.

Comment: It's not just deprecated, it's actually been removed in Python 3.x.

Comment: Why removed? @RogerFan

Comment: `[x for x in 'a n" "c' if x.isalpha()]` would work too

Comment: @Tim Because it fits better as a method. You can call it on every string and you would never call it on something that isn't a string. And it's removed because, ideally, there should only be one right way to do things, and having `split` as a method makes more sense and is more convenient than having to import a module.

Comment: @RogerFan: does that mean a script in Python 2.7 can't be run by Python 3.x?

Comment: @Tim In general, Python 2.x code is not always valid Python 3.x code. That's the whole point of Python 3, making all the backward-incompatible changes that they felt needed to be made. To see some of the most commonly used changes, see [this post](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html).

Answer (score 4):

`str.split()` is not that sophisticated; what you want is [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) instead:

```
re.split(r'[ "]+', some_string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[ "]+', 'a n" "c')
['a', 'n', 'c']
```

Comment: thanks, Martijn. When there is preceding or trailing whitespace, there will be empty strings after splitting. For example, `re.split(r'[ "]+', '  a n" "c ')` will return `['', 'a', 'n', 'c', '']`. How can I avoid those empty strings?

Comment: @Tim: `re.findall(r'[^ "]+', ' a n" "c ')` .